# Choropleth Mapbox showing values = 0 when reading a excel file

Tags: python, pandas, choropleth

I'm trying to make a dashboard with a choropleth map, but it seems it can't read the values from a column inside my excel file.

I'm calling the Excel file like this:

```
df = pd.read_excel("MOVIDA.xlsx", sheet_name=0)
```

And the file looks like this:

[image]

I call the column "Buscas" to color the choropleth Map:

```
fig = px.choropleth_mapbox(df, locations="UF",
                       center={"lat": -16.95, "lon": -47.78},
                       geojson=brazil_states, color_continuous_scale="Redor", opacity=0.5,
                       zoom=4,
                       color="Buscas",
                       hover_data={"Estado": True})
```

But when I look at it, all the regions shows values like 0:

[image]

EDIT: it seems like my map is getting the lowest values from the locations. When I replace all my "0" to another value it worked. I thought it was supposed to sum all the values from the column.

Comment: Is it possible the values in "Buscas" are strings instead of floats ? The hover popup shows 'Buscas=0' which seems to indicate it indeed used "Buscas" for coloring, but with incorrect values.

Comment: I tried to read the file as "dtype={'Buscas': float}", but the result is the same

Answer (score 2):

Since the continents automatically displayed by location specification in plotly are limited, we need to associate geojson attributes with user data. In this case, "sigla" in geojson corresponds to "UF" in user data. Since the data provided is partial data, only some states are filled in.
Since there is no geo data provided, I got it from [here](https://github.com/codeforgermany/click_that_hood/blob/main/public/data/brazil-states.geojson).

```
from urllib import request
import json

url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/codeforgermany/click_that_hood/main/public/data/brazil-states.geojson'
with request.urlopen(url) as f:
    brazil_states = json.load(f)

import plotly.express as px

fig = px.choropleth_mapbox(df,
                           locations="UF",
                           center={"lat": -16.95, "lon": -47.78},
                           geojson=brazil_states,
                           featureidkey='properties.sigla', # add
                           color_continuous_scale="Redor",
                           opacity=0.5,
                           zoom=3,
                           color="Buscas",
                           hover_data={"Estado": True},
                           mapbox_style='carto-darkmatter'
                          )

fig.update_layout(autosize=False, height=600, width=800)
fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer, @r-beginners, but that still doesn't work. I have several lines of the same citys and states, and they have different data. Looks like my map is getting the  lowest value from then, that being 0.

When I give these data already summed in Excel they work.

Comment: If there are multiple data for the same state, group them together and sum them. [df.groupby()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html)